# Correlation between two Series returns NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I have two Series:

**Poverty** *size: 46*

```
1967     7.700000
1969     0.200000
1971     2.200000
1974     0.350000
...
2015     6.628261
2016     4.910526
2017     3.898485
2018     5.491429
dtype: float64
```

**Inequality** *size: 37*

```
1980    0.4898
1981    0.4888
1982    0.4815
1983    0.4893
...
2013    0.5267
2014    0.5224
2015    0.5222
2016    0.5212
dtype: float64
```

But when I try to get the correlation between them with: `poverty.corr(inequality, method='pearson')`
all I get a `NaN` as a result. I have others *series* that works with *poverty*, the only that doesn't work is the *inequality*. Can someone help me?

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Prune thank you, I managed to solve it, but I'll keep that in mind next time!

Answer (score 1):

Your indexes are not aligned in the two series you are trying to compute correlations on. I would suggest merging them and then calling corr. Like this:

```
df = pd.concat([Poverty, Inequality], axis = 0, join = 'inner', axis = 1)
df.corr(method = 'pearson')
```

Comment: Thank you! I did the following 
```i = pd.Series(data=data_, index=index_, dtype="str")
conctPvI = pd.concat([poverty, i], axis=1, join='inner')
corrPvI, p_value = pearsonr(conctPvI[0], conctPvI[1])```


But then I'm getting the following error when I calculate the correlation: ```UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')```


I'm searching for a solution but so far I have nothing

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that my indexes were of different types, so I converted one of them to String and the concatenation went just fine, like this:

```
index_ = index_.astype('str')

inequality = pd.Series(data=data_, index=index_)
conctPvI = pd.concat([poverty, inequality], axis=1, join='inner')
```

Comment: Ahhh!! I couldn't have known that from seeing just the visuals. It's always good to have an MRE in your question as someone suggested above. Glad it worked out. All the best!